# mail is not received after sending using phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

> below is my code

im getting **success** displayed on screen but mail is not received

i changed correctly in sendmail.ini file in sendmail folder in xampp and also php.ini file in php folder

*i have checked in spam also*

can someone please help me 
*thank youu!*

```
<?php
if(mail("sender gmail address","subject","message","From: my gmail address")){
   echo "success";
}
else{
   echo "failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: The success of the `mail` function only says that the message got as far as your mail server on localhost, not any further, so check your mail server logs.

Comment: can you tell me where can i check that ? how do i correct it ?

Comment: Refer to your mail server’s docs - it’s not possible for me to tell without more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks its working now !

in C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

initially it was commented.

thankyouuuu